# Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation using ng2-date-countdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, angular, typescript

I, am using ng2-date-countdown to create a count down Timer. But getting an error as

**ERROR in : Unexpected value 'CountDown in C:/Users/anand/source/repos/vootingwebsite/VotingWebsite/node_modules/ng2-date-countdown/dist/countdown.d.ts' declared by the module 'AppModuleShared in C:/Users/anand/source/repos/vootingwebsite/VotingWebsite/ClientApp/app/app.shared.module.ts'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.**

Followed the instruction from  https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng4-date-countdown-timer

**app.shared.module.ts**

```
import { CountDown } from "ng2-date-countdown";

declarations: [
        AppComponent, RegisterComponent, EqualValidator, DashBoardComponent,
        MobileComponent, CountDown
    ],
```

I, haved added to the declaration section inside @NgModule.

I tried to find the solution in google but no luck.

Can anyone please let me know how can I resolve this issue.

Comment: Most likely some version conflict, but its impossible to tell as the src code of the lib isnt available.

Comment: **ng2**-date-countdown or **ng4**-date-countdown, which one are you using?

Comment: Ng2-date-countdown I am using

Comment: Ng2-date-counter

Comment: Per a deleted answer, you should open an issue [in the GitHub repository](https://github.com/matheushf/ng2-date-countdown) if you have problems